# Background image on button not showing

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to add background image to a button in ionic framework. It works fine in chrome, ios simulator but when I try it on actual device then the background is not showing at all.

Here is my template

```
<div class="button-container">
    <button class="btn-stop" (click)="stop()">
  </button>
</div>
```

And here is my scss

```
    .button-container {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 9%;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .btn-stop {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-image: url('../../assets/imgs/bg.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-size: contain;

        &:after {
            content: 'DEMAND STOP';
            font-size: 2rem;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
```

No idea why as it is working on other two i.e. chrome and emulator.

Comment: Is your image url `../../assets/imgs/bg.png` correct in all environments? Check if you can access the image under that url. Maybe you have a different folder structure on devices and don't need the `../../`.

Comment: @fridoo how can I find the correct folder structure on device?

Comment: Please try `background-image: url('../assets/imgs/bg.png');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the answer as I found what was the issue.

For iOS device at least, the path to image should be `assets/imgs/bg.png`.